# Spring kafka record filter with message content

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to filter messages based on its content. For example, when inside a message with json formart like {"shipmentType: "YAW0", "shipmentId":"123","lat":"999.222","log":"888.222"}.
If shipment type is "YAW0", this message should be discarded.
I noticed Spring provided RecordFilterStrategy for this. But when use it with `fatcory.setRecordFilterStrategy(record -> record.value().contains("YAW0"))`. It raised a type casting error. It says record.value() is my customer model object type com.local.spring.kafka.Shipment which can not be casted to String.
May you have a sample to filter based on customer message content's attribute?

Answer (score 2):

The record object is in a type of ConsumerRecord<K, V>, which K is the key of your kafka message key, V is the value of your kafka message body.

I don't know what you defined in your Kafka message key, but the message body must be type of "com.local.spring.kafka.Shipment".

so, your code should be changed to

```
fatcory.setRecordFilterStrategy(record -> record.value().getShipmentType().contains("YAW0"))
```

Comment: yes. I was using 'String' for Value. After change it, it works.